# Solve the system of equations: $u = x/(x+y), v = y/(x+y)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

solve the system of equations

$$
u = \frac{x}{(x+y)} \\ 
v = \frac{y}{(x+y)}
$$
for $x$ and $y$

I've tried using basic linear algebra and I think I'm just rusty. Supposedly the answer is that $x = uv$ and $y = v(1-u). $

Comment: $u$ & $v$ satisfy $u+v=1$ so ... the system does not seem invertible ?

Comment: You must be missing something, since $x= ku, y=kv$ is a solution for all $k\ne0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u=\frac{x}{x+y} \Rightarrow u(x+y)=x ,\quad (u-1)x+uy=0$

$v=\frac{y}{x+y} \Rightarrow v(x+y)=y ,\quad (v-1)y+vx=0$ which means

$\begin{pmatrix} u-1 & u \\
v & v-1\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

$Det(A)=u+v-1=0$ so A is not invertible